# Data not showing properly as per my field in the game

Tags: java, android, json

I made the game in android in this game i want first login and registration through JSON object. I have a API link where JSON Object send data from that url to the server but in my server i get the data something like this android.widget.EditText{b68c34b VFED..CL. ...........
android.widget.EditText{e1e3128 VFED..CL. ...........

Here is the code :-

RegistrationActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    String url = "http://codexpertise.com/codexpertise.com/apitest/signup.php";
    private Button btnRegister;
    private Button btnLinkToLogin;
    private EditText inputFullName;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);

        // Progress dialog
//        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
//        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Register Button Click event
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = inputFullName.getText().toString().trim();
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                compare_version();

                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                } else {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();


                }
            }
        });

        // Link to Login Screen
        btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }


    /**
     * Function to store user in MySQL database will post params(tag, name,
     * email, password) to register url
     */
    private void registerUser(final String name, final String email,
                              final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_register";

        pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
        //  showDialog();

    }

    private void compare_version() {
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject();

        try {
            parameters.put("type", "signup");
            parameters.put("username", inputFullName);
            parameters.put("email", inputEmail);
            parameters.put("mobileno", "8871539601");
            parameters.put("password", inputPassword);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
        JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response;
                            String resp_code = jsonObject.getString("resp_code");
                            String resp_msg = jsonObject.getString("res_response");
                            System.out.println("response version =====" + response);

                            resp_code = "200";
                            if (resp_code.compareTo("200") == 0) {
                                System.out.println("response msg==" + resp_msg);
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "response msg==" + resp_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

            }
        });
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
```

MyApplication.java

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    public static final String TAG = MyApplication.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private static MyApplication mInstance;
    /*deprecated*/




    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }
    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
parameters.put("type", "signup");
parameters.put("username", inputFullName);
parameters.put("email", inputEmail);
parameters.put("mobileno", "8871539601");
parameters.put("password", inputPassword);
```

`inputFullName`, `inputEmail`, and `inputPassword` are `EditText` classes. They are not pure text. The fix is to get the text from these objects using `.getText()`:

```
parameters.put("type", "signup");
parameters.put("username", inputFullName.getText());
parameters.put("email", inputEmail.getText());
parameters.put("mobileno", "8871539601");
parameters.put("password", inputPassword.getText());
```

You might need to add `.toString()` as well:

```
parameters.put("type", "signup");
parameters.put("username", inputFullName.getText().toString());
parameters.put("email", inputEmail.getText().toString());
parameters.put("mobileno", "8871539601");
parameters.put("password", inputPassword.getText().toString());
```